# JHipster Social Login Google Authentication error Cannot POST /signin/google

Tags: jhipster, spring-social, google-openid

Created an application from https://start.jhipster.tech/#/generate-application with JWT and Enabling Social Login, From Google generated the clientID, clientSecret and update the application.yml .

In google console's Client ID for Web application,
**Authorized JavaScript origins**
 are specified as 
http://localhost:8080 
and
 http://localhost:9000

The "**Authorized redirect URIs**" are set as http://localhost:8080/signin/google and http://localhost:9000/signin/google

After *yarn install* , **yarn start** and **.mvnw** ( spring-boot:run ), the application can be run at http://localhost:8080 and http://localhost:9000

Login with google works fine when application is accessed from http://localhost:8080 ,
 when accessed from http://localhost:9000, the social login page says
**Cannot POST /signin/google** and url of the browser change to **http://localhost:9000/signin/google**

Answer (score 1):

By default, the url for the spring social is not defined into the jhipster webpack configuration.

You should modify the file **webpack/webpack.dev.js** to add the **/signin** path to the dev server configuration as follows :

`devServer: {
        contentBase: './target/www',
        proxy: [{
            context: [
                /* jhipster-needle-add-entity-to-webpack - JHipster will add entity api paths here */
                '/api',
                '/management',
                '/swagger-resources',
                '/v2/api-docs',
                '/h2-console',
                '/auth',
                '/signin'
            ],
            target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
            secure: false
        }],
        watchOptions: {
            ignored: /node_modules/
        }
    }`

And in the [google api credentials](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/), you should add in the redirect urls: `http://localhost:9060/signin/google`